# How to start RabbitMQ cluster with IP addresses and no DNS entry?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to create a RabbitMQ cluster using nodes that have no entries in DNS. Even though I have added the respective entries in /etc/hosts, the cluster always fails with this error:

```
$ rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@pcomdvsns1
Clustering node rabbit@pcomdvsns2 with rabbit@pcomdvsns1 ...
Error: {cannot_discover_cluster,"The nodes provided are either offline or not running"}
```

Is DNS entry a must for getting this started?

Comment: I got an update from apps team that they have added entry in dns but it's now a FQDN. No short name & I am still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that in your `/etc/hosts` there is an entry for `pcomdvsns1` pointing to the correct IP, then verify if you can reach your node using:

```
rabbitmqctl status -n rabbit@pcomdvsns1
```

Then check if you have the same erlang cookies on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make cluster taking advantage of rabbitmqctl.

Did you check whether the elrang cookie is same or not between these machine?

If you didn't, the message you said shows to us.